# Nonempty finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed: How to apply the definition of closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

A nonempty finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed. Using the definition of a closed set, I cannot explain this rigorously: A closed set $E$ is one whose every limit point is also a member of the set. A limit point of the set $E$ is defined as a point $p$, whose every neighborhood contains a point $q$, which is $p\neq q$.

Now if $E$ contains finite elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it also means that $E$ does not have any limit points. In that case how can we apply the definition of the closed set to $E$? Since $E$ does not have any limit points, does the definition of closed set becomes valid for it by the definition?

Comment: maybe you can think of it this way. Are there any limit points of E which are not in E? The answer is no. So, E is closed.

Comment: As $\emptyset$ is closed $E$ may be empty as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A closed set $E$ is one whose every limit point is also a member of the set

Note that if $E$ doesn't have limit points, then this definition is trivialy satisfied and thus $E$ is closed. Yes, it is valid. We will show that finite sets don't have limit points.

What is a limit point?

> A point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (or any other topological space) is a **limit point** of $E$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $E$ different from $x$ itself.

First of all the special case: $E$ is empty. Somewhat weird but by the definition the empty set cannot have a limit point because the empty set is an open neighbourhood of itself. Thus it is closed (note that the only two open and closed sets are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$).

So assume that $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a limit point of a finite, nonempty subset $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\not\in E$. Write

$$E=\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}$$

Thus

$$d = \min\big\{\lVert x-a_i\rVert\ \big|\ a_i\in E\big\}$$

is well defined **and** positive (as a minimum over a finite set of positive numbers) since $x\not\in E$.

Define

$$B=\big\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \big|\ \lVert x-y\rVert < d\big\}$$

By definition $B$ is nonempty (because $d>0$), open neighbourhood of $x$.

Since $x\not\in E$ then $E\cap B=\emptyset$ and so $x$ cannot be a limit point of $E$.

Now note that if $x\in E$ then the same reasoning can be applied to $x$ and $E\backslash\{x\}$ to conclude that there is an open neighbourhood of $x$ that doesn't intersect with $E\backslash\{x\}$. In particular $E$ **does not have** limit points. Thus it is closed.

Comment: So, this means my argumentation is correct: If a set does not have any limit points, it becomes automatically closed. I was not sure about that since if a set does not have any limit points, closedness was not explicitly defined.

Comment: @UfukCanBicici The definition still applies. Formally, from the logic point of view the statement $\forall_{x} x\in X\Rightarrow x\in Y$ is always true if $X$ is empty.

Answer (score 1):

First show for any x that {x} is closed.
Now use the fact that the union of two closed sets is closed
to conclude that any finite set, {x,y}, {x,y,z}, ... is closed.